# Using same UIActivityIndicatorView in many view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a simple iOS app with various view controllers. 
Each view controller has different functionality but each view controller has 'load' button, that when triggered, sending a request and getting a result to delegate method.

I want to use an UIActivityIndicatorView that will start when the user will click the button and will stop on the delegate method.
Obviously, I want the indicator to look the same on each VC, so I've made property of it, and on each viewDidLoad method I am using this code:

```
self.indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge]; 
self.indicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.6f];
self.indicator.frame = CGRectMake(40.0, 20.0, 100.0, 100.0);
self.indicator.center = self.view.center;
```

The problem is, I am using the same parameters, on the same object, copping and pasting these lines on every view controller. 
Let's say I want to change the style in the next version, I need to change it 10 times.

What would be the best way to use some kind of static indicator that would be set with these parameters and would be set on and off by demand?

Comment: You can have a custom class for your activity indicator, and have show/hide methods which shows/hide the indicator on/from your current displaying view controller.

Comment: You can use "MBProgressHUD" frame work. Not only this there few more third party frame works is there.

Answer (score 1):

You can create single view controller to display loading indicator in all view controller. You need to write code once, put following code in AppDelegate file.

**Note:** I'm not working in Objective-C, following code in Swift. So you need to transform code in objective C.

First add following code in ProgressVC:

**ProgressVC.swift:**

```
class func viewController() -> ProgressVC {
   return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProgressVC") as! ProgressVC
}
```

Add following code in your AppDelegate.

**AppDelegate.swift:**

```
var progressVC : ProgressVC?
static let shared = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

func showLoading(isShow: Bool) {

    if isShow {

        // Remove progress view if already exist
        if progressVC != nil {
            progressVC?.view.removeFromSuperview()
            progressVC = nil
        }

        progressVC = ProgressVC.viewController()
        AppDelegate.shared.window?.addSubview((progressVC?.view)!)

    } else {

        if progressVC != nil {
            progressVC?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you need to call just above method with AppDelegate's shared instance. Enable animated property of UIActivityIndicatorView from storyboard.

**Show:**

```
AppDelegate.shared.showLoading(isShow: true)
```

**Hide:**

```
AppDelegate.shared.showLoading(isShow: false)
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot of progress vc]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the one i use in swift 4.1

```
import UIKit

class ProgressView {

    // MARK: - Variables
    private var containerView = UIView()
    private var progressView = UIView()
    private var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    static var shared = ProgressView()

    // To close for instantiation
    private init() {}

    // MARK: - Functions
     func startAnimating(view: UIView = (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view)!) {
        containerView.center = view.center
        containerView.frame = view.frame
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0xffffff, alpha: 0.5)

        progressView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80)
        progressView.center = containerView.center
        progressView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0x444444, alpha: 0.7)
        progressView.clipsToBounds = true
        progressView.cornerRadius = 10

        activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
        activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: progressView.bounds.width/2, y: progressView.bounds.height/2)

        activityIndicator.style = .whiteLarge

        view.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(progressView)
        progressView.addSubview(activityIndicator)

        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    /// animate UIActivityIndicationView without blocking UI
    func startSmoothAnimation(view: UIView = (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view)!) {
        activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
        activityIndicator.center = view.center
        activityIndicator.style = .whiteLarge
        activityIndicator.color = UIColor.gray
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    func stopAnimatimating() {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        containerView.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}

extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hex: UInt32, alpha: CGFloat) {
        let red = CGFloat((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/256.0
        let green = CGFloat((hex & 0xFF00) >> 8)/256.0
        let blue = CGFloat(hex & 0xFF)/256.0
        self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
}

// usage 
 ProgressView.shared.startAnimating()
// to stop 
 ProgressView.shared.stopAnimatimating()
Hope it helps
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you create a superclass to your view controllers and add the spinner functionality there, and let your view controllers inherit from it.

The superclass view controller would look something like this:

```
// .h-file
@interface SuperclassViewController : UIViewController

- (void)showIndicator;
- (void)hideIndicator;

@end
```

---

```
// .m file
#import "SuperclassViewController.h"

@interface SuperclassViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;    
@end

@implementation SuperclassViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    self.indicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.6f];
    self.indicator.frame = CGRectMake(40.0, 20.0, 100.0, 100.0);
    self.indicator.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
    self.indicator.center = self.view.center;

    [self.indicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)showIndicator {
    [self.view addSubview:self.indicator];
}

- (void)hideIndicator {
    [self.indicator removeFromSuperview];
}
@end
```

---

Now, to inherit it do the following in your view controllers .h file:

```
#import "SuperclassViewController.h"

@interface YourViewController : SuperclassViewController;

/** properties and methods */

@end
```

Then you can call `[self showIndicator]` and `[self hideIndicator]` in your view controllers whenever needed without any extra coding.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the activity indicator in the `UIWindow` and then you could show/hide it from any `UIViewController`.

To get the window use:
`UIApplication.shared.keyWindow`

Comment: Do you mean the UIWindow in the app delegate? If now, how can I reach it?

Comment: Won't this do Bad Things™ if there's a pop-up alert current visible on the screen, because the pop-up will be the `keyWindow`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your assistance,
I decided to make a singleton class that has a variable of UIActivityIndicatorView.

This is the declaration of the class:

```
#import "ProgressView.h"

@interface ProgressView()

@property (nonatomic) UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;
+(ProgressView *)shared;
@end

@implementation ProgressView

+ (ProgressView *)shared {
    static ProgressView* sharedVC = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedVC = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedVC;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        self.indicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.6f];
        self.indicator.frame = CGRectMake(40.0, 20.0, 100.0, 100.0);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)startAnimation:(UIView *)view {
    self.indicator.center = view.center;
    self.indicator.hidden = NO;
    [self.indicator startAnimating];
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 12 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        if ([self.indicator isAnimating])
            [self stopAnimation];
    });
    [view addSubview:self.indicator];
}

- (void)stopAnimation {
    if ([self.indicator isAnimating]) {
        [self.indicator stopAnimating];
        [self.indicator removeFromSuperview];  
    }
}
@end
```

Please note I have added a rule that if the indicator didn't get triggered to stop in 12 seconds the class would stop the indicator by itself.

Now, all I have to do is to add this line in every place in my code where I would like to start the indicator:

```
 [[ProgressView shared] startAnimation:self.view];
```

And to add this line to stop it:

```
 [[ProgressView shared] stopAnimation];
```